# Adding an Attribute COLSPAN using Javascript Using an data-id Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, odoo

Good Day! I am only new in programming javascript I have this problem theres a table Tag with a Theader with an Attribute of data-id now I just want to add a Colspan Dynamically using this data-id tag to find the specific Column to add a COLSPAN attribute

I've created this code of mine

```
 $('th[data-id="param_name_3_check"]').remove();
```

This is to remove a table header in a Table in Javascript, and try to use the following code to add some attribute.

```
$('th[data-id="param_name_1_value"]').createAttribute("colspan", "9");
```

But theres an error, is it possible to add an Attribute via data-id?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set attribute like this:

```
$('th[data-id="param_name_1_value"]').attr("colspan", "9");
```

[fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/112g/Lnb6jz26/)

Comment: Thanks sir, you're badass :D

Comment: sir how about the inside of the th Tag , there is a div tag inside the th tag and I want to add some attribute also in the Div Tag Thanks

Comment: $('th[data-id="param_name_2_check"] > div').attr("style", "color:green"); [see fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/112g/yr20Lw6z/)

Comment: sir do you have any tutorial or website links for beginner like to javascript?

Comment: read about jquery (selectors, dom manipulation) and angular.js